# Does JLabel have default implementation of mouseMotionListener?

Tags: java, swing, mousemotionlistener

I want to ask if `JLabel has` default implementation of `mouseMotionListener`.

I use `addAWTEventListener` method to `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()` with `MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK` in order to runtime it will be able to know over which control the mouse is. Over `jButton, jFrame, jTextfield` everything work fine but over JLabel , JPanel and others do not.

If I add to `JLabel` the code above

```
lblNewLabel_1.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
```

it  works.

I have to add something similar to all controls which now haven't `MouseMotionListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public class something implements MouseMotionListener{    

      public something(){
        button.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        JTextField.addMouseMotionListener(this);          
      }   

//MouseMotionListener methods

     @Override
     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }     
}
```

**And yes you must add a mouseOrMotion Listener or action Listener if you expect an action from them**

And something more when you want to add a JLabel to window don't add it directly but first add the JLabel to a JPanel and then window.add(panel).
Cause **JLabel is lightweight** component and **JFrame heavyweight** and may cause you a lot of problems with listeners.

Let me know if that's not enough...

Comment: I will try your suggestion. I didn't know that you can implement a Listener and add it to all the components with this way.

Comment: yes pagratios you can implement and actionListener,MouseListener and generally any Interface or Class and also you can extend a Class.If you need help on that let me know.. to edit